# Is it okay for the author field to contain names of research labs?

Tags: citations, bibtex

I find most articles through EBSCO and similar search tools, then export the BibTeX details to my own `bibliography.bib` file. Recently, I found some BibTeX files with a strange author field, containing not just the name of a person, but also of a research lab or a college. E.g.:

> Author = {White, R. R. and West College Child Development Laboratory}

When compiled in APA format, it looks very odd:

> White, R. R. and Laboratory, W. C. C. D.

Are there situations in which it is correct to place such lab or school details directly in the author field? If not, where do I need to relocate this information to?

Answer (score 5):

I have seen labs signing papers in cases of very big collaborations. If that is how it is cited in the journal, you should adjust your bib file [like so](http://timmurphy.org/2011/02/15/using-an-organisation-name-as-an-author-in-bibtex/) (thanks to Federico Poloni for the fix):

```
Author = "White, R. R. and {West College Child Development Laboratory}"
```

Comment: I think that the correct format should be `Author = "White, R. R. and {West College Child Development Laboratory}"`, so that the first author gets formatted according to the bibtex style.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni You are correct, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

What does the article itself look like if you pull it up from the journal itself? You should probably adjust your record of it to match whatever the article actually says. This could be a problem with the machine parsing of the original document, or the journal may have accepted the "authorship" of the lab as a convention in that field.